# move mouse or touchscreen in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On our site, if you are inactive after an hour, we log you out.  There are certain pages on our webpage like downloading files that we'd like to not log you out.  The third party directive we are using monitors things like:

```
mousemove keydown touchstart touchmove
```

Is there an easy way that on these pages to include a directive that just fakes a `mousemove touchstart` event so the third party directive doesn't log us out?

Comment: Sounds like a hack. Instead you should modify the directive to be disabled while downloading

Comment: Like dman said, it sounds like a hack. You might be able to put something together that uses testing methodologies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555326/how-do-i-trigger-a-mousemove-event-in-an-angularjs-unit-test

Comment: Also, what is the directive that you are using?